# Need to Mint 1 NFT using Js and new Metaplex createNft: Fails ...Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit

Tags: web3.js, metaplex, mint

I am trying to create one Js script to mint 1 NFT to test new Metaplex function **createNft** on: https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/getting-started/js

I am testing on Devnet.
I am providing a test wallet with funds in Devnet.
I am providing mint.js, package.json and output.
node version: v18.15.0

Thanks in advance !

**mint.js**

```
import { Keypair, SystemProgram, TransactionInstruction, Transaction, Connection, PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js';
import {
    generateSigner,
    signerIdentity,
    percentAmount,
    publicKey
} from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";
import { createUmi } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults';
import {
    createNft,
    mintV1,
    createV1,
    fetchDigitalAsset,
    TokenStandard,
    mplTokenMetadata
} from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'


// *** Init

// Create connection to the network
const connection = new Connection('https://api.devnet.solana.com');
const TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID = new PublicKey('TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA');

// Read the keypair from byteArray
const secret = new Uint8Array([43, 6, 89, 198, 35, 211, 28, 143, 52, 141, 173, 50, 44, 40, 73, 73, 36, 59, 18, 43, 212, 76, 220, 75, 190, 66, 226, 200, 43, 4, 21, 38, 54, 153, 59, 206, 235, 98, 154, 46, 216, 138, 172, 203, 207, 78, 213, 240, 34, 53, 153, 15, 228, 27, 101, 192, 118, 125, 5, 73, 69, 166, 92, 230]);
const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(secret);

// Create a keypair using the eddsa interface from the umi context
const umi = createUmi('https://api.devnet.solana.com').use(mplTokenMetadata());
const myKeypair = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(secret);
const umiSigner = generateSigner(umi, myKeypair);
umi.use(signerIdentity(umiSigner));


// *** Generate a new mint account
let mintAccount = Keypair.generate();

let createMintAccountIx = SystemProgram.createAccount({
    fromPubkey: keypair.publicKey,
    newAccountPubkey: mintAccount.publicKey,
    lamports: await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(500),
    space: 500,
    programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
});

// Create a new transaction and add the create mint account instruction
let transaction = new Transaction().add(createMintAccountIx);
let signature = await connection.sendTransaction(transaction, [keypair, mintAccount]);
console.log(signature)

// Confirm the minting transaction
const mintConfirmation = await connection.confirmTransaction(signature);
console.log('transaction confirmation:', mintConfirmation);

// Add a delay to ensure the ledger is updated
console.log('Waiting for the ledger to update...');
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));

// Keep checking the mint account balance until it is positive
const payerBalance = await connection.getBalance(keypair.publicKey);
let mintAccountBalance = 0;
while (mintAccountBalance <= 0) {
    mintAccountBalance = await connection.getBalance(mintAccount.publicKey);
    console.log('Mint account balance:', mintAccountBalance);
    console.log('Payer balance:', payerBalance);
    if (mintAccountBalance <= 0) {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    }
}

// Create NFT using Metaplex https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/getting-started/js
await createNft(umi, {
    mint: mintAccount.publicKey,
    name: 'My NFT',
    uri: 'https://example.com/my-nft.json',
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(5.5),
}).sendAndConfirm(umi)
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata": "^3.0.0",
    "@metaplex-foundation/umi": "^0.8.9",
    "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults": "^0.8.9",
    "@metaplex/js": "^4.12.0",
    "@solana/spl-token": "^0.3.8",
    "@solana/web3.js": "^1.78.5"
  }
}
```

**output after executing: node mint.js**

```
SouSwHsg97XLkckkXdYXeKMbJKJVJij8QLyGVs1uPYszN4NH92jG8rwxLf4oScGrVhXe3x3t222LBiLFnP21Yag
transaction confirmation: { context: { slot: 244902994 }, value: { err: null } }
Waiting for the ledger to update...
Mint account balance: 4370880
Payer balance: 3628931040
/mypath/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:12412
              throw new SendTransactionError('failed to send transaction: ' + res.error.message, _logs2);
                    ^

SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit.
    at Connection._callee89$ (/mypath/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:12412:21)
    at tryCatch (/mypath/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:45:16)
    at Generator.<anonymous> (/mypath/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:133:17)
    at Generator.next (/mypath/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:74:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/mypath/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
    at _next (/mypath/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:22:9)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  logs: []
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some tests, seems that the problem was some wrong library imports in my code. Some methods are used in different metaplex libraries, with different result. I took the Jimmi NFT object and merged a final and very simple working code that can be executed right away:

```
import { createNft, mplTokenMetadata } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata';
import { createUmi } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults';
import { percentAmount, generateSigner, keypairIdentity } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";


// Wallet with funds in Devnet
const secret = [6, 75, 114, 41, 237, 21, 146, 239, 34, 199, 207, 63, 78, 73, 16, 187, 113, 38, 228, 73, 244, 253, 210, 84, 197, 26, 247, 50, 181, 61, 184, 221, 208, 236, 132, 116, 6, 84, 36, 102, 26, 230, 69, 156, 226, 121, 29, 12, 240, 33, 123, 145, 229, 194, 213, 51, 46, 233, 45, 36, 106, 221, 171, 221];
const uintSecret = Uint8Array.from(secret);

// Umi
const umi = createUmi('https://api.devnet.solana.com');
const keypair = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(uintSecret);
umi.use(keypairIdentity(keypair)).use(mplTokenMetadata())

// Mint
const nftMint = generateSigner(umi);
await createNft(umi, {
    mint: nftMint,
    name: `Uminft`,
    symbol: 'UMI',
    uri: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/687c/solana-nft-native-client/main/metadata.json',
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(5),
    isCollection: false,
}).sendAndConfirm(umi);

// Show token address
console.log(nftMint.publicKey)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you have no funds. Probably being caused by `umiSigner` Try airdropping some when running the script or use `mykeypair` as your umi Identity.

Here is a shortened script that works on my end for minting an NFT using `umi`

```
import {secret} from './setup';
import { createNft, mplTokenMetadata } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata';
import { createUmi } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults';

const umi = createUmi('https://api.devnet.solana.com');

const keypair = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(uintSecret);

umi.use(keypairIdentity(keypair))
    .use(mplTokenMetadata())

// ? create a collection mint
const collectionMint = generateSigner(umi);
const createCollectionTx = async () => {
    await createNft(umi, {
        mint: collectionMint,
        name: `Kobeni`,
        symbol: 'KBN',
        uri: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/687c/solana-nft-native-client/main/metadata.json',
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(5.5), // 5.5%
        isCollection: false,
    }).sendAndConfirm(umi);
}
createCollectionTx()
    .then(res => res)
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-umi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine": "^6.0.0",
    "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata": "^3.0.0",
    "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-toolbox": "^0.9.1",
    "@metaplex-foundation/umi": "^0.8.9",
    "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults": "^0.8.9",
    "@metaplex-foundation/umi-program-repository": "^0.8.9",
    "@metaplex-foundation/umi-signer-wallet-adapters": "^0.8.9",
    "@solana/web3.js": "^1.78.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jimmi, my wallet has funds as printed: Payer balance: 3628931040
I've tried many other ideas like generate and airdrop, but got same error.
I also tried your code, but can't make it work with my secret, and a generated one too. I see that you're creating it from uintSecret, but i can't see this const declared. Can you update the code with a test secret to check if works correctly in my end ? All that I tried fails with: Error: provided secretKey is invalid or bad secret key size.
I can't make this work: const keypair = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(uintSecret);

Comment: yes, your `myKeypair` has balance in it, but `umiSigner` doesn't. This is where I think your error is coming from. 

Can you try it with the code I've shared.

Comment: Hi Jimmi, thanks for your help so far !
umiSigner is using the same wallet than signer, loaded from the secret bitArray.
I tried your code with my wallet(secret) and failed with errors that i added to my last comment.
I did manage to generate a new one in the code, fund it, and execute your mint code, but fails the same way:

Generated public key: 7dhNv3Nxh8boYEMuZmr35h1ndqsUrCqGZ4S8gbG2Qckj
Airdrop successful
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit.

Will continue testing

Comment: actually, `const umiSigner = generateSigner(umi, myKeypair);` should be failing because the function takes in one argument. According to the docs, ' generateSigner generates a new signer cryptographically. Under the hood, this method uses `generateKeypair`' https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/umi/blob/main/docs/publickeys-signers.md

Comment: @Harlock, have you tried to mint with the code I provided?

Comment: yes, but the problem is the wallet key. Same problem with my key.
Do you mind to try with the secret in my code just to verify ?

Comment: This code works for me:
const umiSigner = generateSigner(umi, myKeypair);

Indeed it fails if I remove umi from parameters.
There should be a problem with libraries or versions.

Can you share your package.json ?
mine is in the post info.

Cheers

Comment: umi parameter is used as context:
const generateSigner = context => createSignerFromKeypair(context, context.eddsa.generateKeypair());

Comment: I just minted using your key. https://explorer.solana.com/tx/5QnsRiAZ6Kz5YmLknPKtHB1E28Qpa6V1SrVb7CvP9jJrLiN7jnhHh5ffizHN8k6r9Eu8xwfGjXCZL8ND27jbUJTj?cluster=devnet

Comment: Hi Jimmi. There should be a misunderstanding here because your code is incomplete, and also throw some errors. I can't make it work:
You need to add this line: const uintSecret = Uint8Array.from(secret);
| And in my side I have to modify the import due to (SyntaxError: Named export 'generateSigner' not found. The requested module '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.)
Can you share the full code you're running ? Thanks mate !

Comment: thanks Jimmi, very appreciate your help. I have used your NFT object to complete the solution in other post. If need anything you got a friend here !

Comment: Huh, this had 0 upvotes but everyone seems to have found it helpful. Remember to upvote good answers people!